# How to use django-compressor to compress form media offline

Tags: django, django-compressor

A Django template (containing a form with media) that includes a snippet like the one below would throw an error when using django-compressor with `COMPRESS_OFFLINE=True`, because `form` is not available when offline compression is executed:

```
# Template snippet
{% compress js %}
{{ form.media.js }}
{% endcompress %}
```

Generally speaking, django-compressor provides the COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT setting to handle similar situations.  However, if a site contains many such forms or widgets with media, this solution isn't ideal.

For example, currently, I do something like this in settings.py (for each widget's media):

```
# settings.py
...
from my_app1.widgets import Widget1
from my_app1.widgets import Widget2
from my_app1.widgets import Widget3
...
widgets = {
    'my_widget1': Widget1(),
    'my_widget2': Widget2(),
    'my_widget3': Widget3(),
    ...
}
for name, widget in widgets.items():
    COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT['{}_css'.format(name)] = widget.media['css']
    COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT['{}_js'.format(name)] = widget.media['js']
```

And then in templates, I do this:

```
{% compress js %}
{{ my_widget1_js }}
{% endcompress %}
```

Is there a way to handle this situation in a manner that more closely resembles Django's `{{ form.media }}` method, or perhaps without needing to enumerate the specific media to every widget or every form (containing media) in the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your settings by using some custom class with an `__getattr__` method. That way if you will pass that object into template and try to call

```
{{ obj.my_widget1_js }}
```

logic inside `__getattr__` can search for specified widget in your project and return it's media.

Example of class that will auto-discover each widget:

```
class WidgetImporter(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        path = name.split('__') # this will split path on double underscore, so you can define submodule here
        path = [(node, "".join(part.capitalize() for part in node.split('_'))) for node in path] # this will convert underscore_names to CamelCase names.

        # determining for each module if it's name is CamelCased or underscored
        real_path = []
        for underscored, cameled in path:
            try:
                __import__(".".join(real_path + [underscored])) # first trying to import umderscored module
            except ImportError:
                try:
                    __import__(".".join(real_path + [cameled])) # now try with cameled
                except ImportError:
                    return "" # or raise some exception here if you like
                else:
                    real_path.append(cameled)
            else:
                real_path.append(underscored)

        last_node = real_path[len(real_path) - 1]
        return getattr(__import__(".".join(real_path), fromlist=[last_node]), last_node)() # returning actual class instance
```

That way you can use it inside your settings.py file:

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = {
    'widgets': WidgetImporter(),
}
```

and use in your template:

```
{{ widgets.my_app1__widgets__widget1.media.css }}
```

Class will try to resolve `my_app1__widgets__widget1` to actual path to your class and will try to import it. If it succeeds, it's `media['css']` will be printed. It's not 100% optimal code and 100% safe (there can be some vulnerabilities if someone has access to your templates), but it will do the job.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestion, but it seems like doing that would lead to code shuffling, rather than simplifying the code.  I'm not sure I see the advantage since each widget would still need to be instantiated, enumerated, and added to COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT in settings.py.  If I'm missing something in your suggestion, can you clarify it with an example settings.py and custom widget class?

Comment: I mean that using custom class, you can implement some auto discovering of your widgets, so you don't have to hardcode list of it. I'm pretty sure that there is no other way than using `COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT` without editing `django-compressor` package.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer and I now have a clear understanding of what your suggestion is.  I can see how this method at least shifts from a static enumeration in settings.py to one that allows for more dynamic usage within the template.